# Bitnami Drupal redirect to www version of url

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, drupal-7, bitnami

I am using Bitnami Drupal 7.22 AWS cloud image as web server.

I have only one Drupal site running on it that was accessible via "www.example.com/drupal"

I used the following command to redefine the path to root.

```
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/bnconfig --appurl /
```

Now I need to enable redirect rule to "www" version of url from htaccess.conf, after un-commenting these lines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The URL example.com redirects to www.example.com/drupal that is no more Drupal root.

What am I missing here to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing following line to comment out in `/opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/conf/drupal.conf`

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /drupal/ [PT]
```

And this fixed the problem But I am still confused how was the site running without "/drupal" suffix.